# SignalR and object based payloads

Tags: c#, signalr

I'm playing a bit with SignalR and relating it back to some previous Pub/Sub work.  In it, we have a Base Event with a couple of mandatory properties and then several Derived Events for specific payloads.

With SignalR, it appears that I need to define a hub based on each of the derived events as Send is going to deal with a specific type.  For example, if I create a hub for the base class I can send any of the derived types or the base type without error but I always get back a base type losing any of the derived type's properties.

Seems my choices are a hub for each type or putting the derived properties in some type of blob to be parsed out by the receiver.

How far off is my thinking?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, SignalR is based on a dynamic way to describe and (de)serialize payloads, so its runtime tries to match the type specified on the receiving part, without trying to further match any derived type. It's a mechanism which has the advantage of being able to work without requiring to share types across clients and server, but the disadvantage you are experiencing. This should explain what you see.

You could base your solution on the usage of `dynamic`, if you want to keep your hierarchy of payloads you'll have to take care yourself of deserialize the received `dynamic` value into instances of those, maybe with the help of a "record type" member on the base class. You would not need to do a full parsing.